# Remove unused Optane drive, laptop will not boot

Tags: windows, hard-drive, optane

HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop 15-cx0xxx Windows 11 Bios InsydeH20 Rev 5.0 version F.28
Has PCIe Intel MEMPEC1J016GAH Optane drive and 2.5" solid state drive

Both show as Non-RAID Physical disks in BIOS / UEFI Devices
There is no option to disable either in BIOS
Running Intel Rapid Storage App shows Optane as disabled.
The drive does not show up in windows explorer and shows as unformatted in disk management

From everything I see, this device is not being used for anything, but when I remove it and boot, I get a message that no OS is found.
My ultimate goal is to add a new NVME drive but my immediate goal is to just remove this drive and still be able to boot.
All information I have been able to find indicate I need to disable the Optane drive with Intel App, but it already shows as disabled. Any suggestions on what I need to do? Thank you

[disk partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8fK9.jpg)

[Optane setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhS3X.jpg)

Comment: If you intend to remove the optane drive then you shouldn't be using Intel RST. Before doing what you did you should've installed AHCI support in Windows *then* change to AHCI mode.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I will have to research this as I am not sure how to install AHCI support or change to AHCI mode

Comment: I followed several tutorials and unable to find AHCI option in BIOS
https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-enable-ahci-in-windows-10-after-installation
for example

Comment: The setting is "SATA Operation mode" or something similar. It can be a sub-menu somewhere, it varies a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately there a chance it isn't user accessible in UEFI or anywhere else for that matter due to locked down HP firmware. Many users are complaining about that: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Boot-and-Lockup/Disable-Intel-RST-in-Laptop-BIOS/td-p/8275849 so it may not be possible to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ChanganAuto is correct that HP BIOS is garbage and does not allow what I am looking to do.
To close this out, I created a windows restore usb drive, removed both existing hard drives, put the new NVME drive in, installed windows there, put the 2.5" SSD back in, and am now running without the Optane drive.
Thank you everyone for taking a look.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the bootloader is in that drive, so when you remove it it says no OS. once my system reserved partition too moved to my other drive, and i had to perform a clean install. But this can't be the case as you said it is unpartitioned.

If you can, attach a screenshot of you disk management pls. it will help diagnose the issue further.

---

---

**EDIT**

Your system reserved partition is missing, which gives a hint that it may be on the other drive. Even though it says its unallocated, it still could contain data. It has happened to me a lot (specially in my USB)

**What you have to do to fix**

https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager-software/clone-and-move-system-reserved-partition-to-another-drive.html   Refer this link and see how to Clone your system reserved partiton from one drive to another. There is a possibility of this working, whereas the cloning mostly doesn't end up sucessfull but cause more problems.

Comment: Thank you, I attached a screen shot to the question above.

Comment: My post was edited, check if the solution helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).